# In sonarqube 6.5 version, does 1.7 cobertura plugin works?

Tags: sonarqube

sonarqube 6.5 version, cobertura plugin has been not compatible . so cobertura plugin doesnt work in new version 6.5?IS there any replacement plugin for this cobertura in sonarqube version 6.5

Comment: could you edit your question and be clearer please ? Your first sentence is hard to understand. Do you mean you have some plugin on 6.5 that are not compatible ? From what to what? 1.7 to 6.5? looks quite a big gap.
Explain a bit better please.

Comment: See [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) page. The plug is incompatible after SonarQube 6.0; it is not very likely an SonarSource update will be posted.